# TouchGFX gui automated testing

Tags: c++, stm32, stm32cubeide, touchgfx

Checking for feasibility of automated UI testing for TouchGFX. Is there a library that helps in identifying the application window handle and use it to choose UI elements and drive the operations in each window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work as part of the TouchGFX team on a daily basis.

We have a test-framework, only for internal use currently, that we plan to share with the public at some point. It uses the CubeProgrammer API to, through `UnitTest++`, step an application `x` number of times, dump the frame-buffer and do comparisons against golden images, check render times, and lots more. We use it for both framework unit tests, TouchGFX Generator tests and to test the board packages available through TouchGFX Designer.

What prevents you from performing this kind of test, currently, is that you need a HAL that isn't free-running and can take instructions from a PC source (Executing test-suites through UnitTest++, sending commands over CubeProgrammer API).

I hope we'll be able to share it soon.